# Clubbing two files after every 12 lines in hp-ux system

Tags: linux, unix, merge, paste, hp-ux

I have two large files .one file contains 0-12 Hrs of data and other contain 13-23 hours of data . 
I want to merge it in a single file with 23-0 hours for each combination.

```
ex :
file1

abcdefg00
abcdefg01
abcdefg02
---------
---------
abcdefg12
pqrstuv00
---------
---------

file2 :

abcdefg13
abcdefg14
---------
---------
abcdefg23
pqrstuv13
---------
---------
```

Is there any way that i can merge like this . output should be like below

```
>     abcdefg00
>     abcdefg01
>     abcdefg02
>     ---------
>     ---------
>     abcdefg12
>     abcdefg13
>     abcdefg14
>     ---------
>     ---------
>     abcdefg23
>     pqrstuv00
>     ---------
>     ---------
>     pqrstuv13
>     ---------
>     ---------
>     pqrstuv23
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Hi kiran, welcome on SuperUser. Register yourself and check if the answers work in your case. If not add some comment or [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to append the two files, one after the other, but to also reverse the order of the lines, you can use either `tail -r` or `tac` as in

```
cat file1 file2 | tail -r
```

or

```
cat file1 file2 | tac
```

The -r option may not be available on HP-UX `tail`. The command `tac` is part of coreutils if you need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to  use `sort`

```
sort -n -k1 f1.txt f2.txt   > newfile
```

from `man sort` you can read that `sort`

> Writes sorted concatenation of all FILE(s) to standard output.

You may need to select the column used to sort (`-k1`) or to select a numbering sort `-n`.

If your files are not strictly ordered you should do a script that reads 12 lines alternatively from the first and the second file with two file descriptors <sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26605/66388)],[[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26604/66388)]</sup>.

It can result in something similar to  this one

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  for ((i=1;i<=12;i++)); do
    read -r f1 <&3 && echo "$f1" || exit 1
  done
  for ((i=1;i<=12;i++)); do
    read -r f2 <&4 && echo "$f2" || exit 2
  done
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Until is able to read it writes else it exit with different error value if from the 1st or the 2nd cycle.